# Tuple not returning sum over columns - Python, csv

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
import csv

myfile = r'csvlist.csv'

with open(myfile, 'r', newline='') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    i = next(c).index('Wasted Years')
    filtering = [row for row in c if row[i] == '25']
    total = sum(float(row["Prices"]) for row in c)
    print(filtering, "The total is %s" % total)
```

The `filtering` part works well, but the `total` one, it is supposed to iterate over some items on the column, and output a total from these items, but it prints `0` for some reason, any ideas?

```
i iterates over a int column, which has data on each cell, like: 25, 18, 30, etc, and filters by a specific number, in this case '25'
total it's supposed to sum everything on Prices column and output a total, these are float-like records
```

Comment: Any reason to choose the `csv` module over `pandas`? I’m not very familiar with the former, but in my experience the latter is pretty great.

Comment: Hi Alexander, yes, sadly, this is an excercise, so it's not supposed to use Pandas, and yes, You are right, Pandas will sort this pretty quick, lol :(

Comment: What do you see if you print the generator (just transform it into a list comprehension when debugging) before calling `sum()` on it? I’m guessing it’s empty?

Comment: Yes, you guessed right, it returns 0

Comment: Wait, just the number `0`? Or a list `[0]`? Could you share the csv file to make it easier for others to help? See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Solution

`c` is a `csv.reader` object, it is also an iterable: you can iterate through it only once. The first time you iterate through `c` is when you calculate `filtering`. After that, `c` becomes empty. One way to deal with this is to create two iterables: `c1` and `c2` that are identical:

```
import itertools
import csv

with open(myfile, 'r', newline='') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    c1, c2 = tee(c)  # Split into 2 separate iterables

    # Use the first iterable, c1
    i = next(c1).index('Wasted Years')
    filtering = [row for row in c1 if row[i] == '25']

    # Use a different iterable, c2
    next(c2)  # Skip the header row
    total = sum(float(row["Prices"]) for row in c2)
    print(filtering, "The total is %s" % total)
```

## Second Solution

Another solution is to rewind the file pointer to the beginning before iterating through `c` the second time:

```
import csv

myfile = r'csvlist.csv'

with open(myfile, 'r', newline='') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    i = next(c).index('Wasted Years')
    filtering = [row for row in c if row[i] == '25']

    f.seek(0)   # Rewind the file to the beginning
    next(c)     # Skip the header row
    total = sum(float(row["Prices"]) for row in c)
    print(filtering, "The total is %s" % total)
```

## Third Solution

I found out what you and I did wrong: The first time calculating the `filtering`, we use `csv.reader`, but the second time when calculating the total, we treated the reader as if it was a `csv.DictReader`. Let's use `csv.DictReader` all the way through:

```
import csv

myfile = r'csvlist.csv'

with open(myfile, 'r', newline='') as f:
    c = csv.DictReader(f)
    filtering = [row for row in c if row['Wasted Years'] == '25']

    # Rewind and skip header
    f.seek(0)
    next(f)

    total = sum(float(row["Prices"]) for row in c)
    print(filtering, "The total is %s" % total)
```

I have a feeling that you want to calculate the total from the filtering, not the whole csv rows. If that it the case:

```
    total = sum(float(row["Prices"]) for row in filtering) # filtering, not c
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I'm a bit baffled at itertools, on the first solution, it says 'tee' nameerror not defined, I'm using python 3.7, but you are right, sounds quite logical to split it into two iterables, the second solution throws, list indices must be integers or slices, not str, I guess the reason is that we are specifying "Prices" which is actually a header? Thank You very much

Comment: Please see my third solution.